# Canvas iOS Safari SecurityError: DOM Exception 18

Tags: javascript, ios, html, canvas, safari

I am trying to manipulate a video on canvas using all assets from the same domain. I am running this through apache and using my local IP to access the site. This all seems to be working on mobile chrome but for some reason it is throwing security exceptions on safari on iOS. Maybe there is a bug in how the canvas is tainted from using two different canvas's and passing around the video? Anyway I was hoping there was a work around? Here is my code and exception:

**HTML:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>
<h1>DOH</h1>
    <video id="video" width="800" height="600" src="doh.mp4" controls></video>
    <canvas width="800" height="600" id="output"></canvas>
    <button id="doh">Play</button>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="custom.js"></script>
</body>
```

**JS:**

```
var v = document.getElementById('video');
var canvas = document.getElementById('output');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var back = document.createElement('canvas');
var backcontext = back.getContext('2d');
var R = 10, G = 10, B = 10, dev = 10; 
//var R = 57, G = 94, B = 118, dev = 10; 
var hR = (R + dev), lR = (R - dev), hG = (G + dev), lG = (G - dev), hB = (B + dev), lB = (B - dev);

var cw,ch;

var click = document.getElementById('doh');

click.addEventListener('click', function(){
    v.play();
});

v.style.position = "absolute";
v.style.top = window.innerHeight; 

v.addEventListener('play', function(){
    cw = v.clientWidth;
    ch = v.clientHeight;
    canvas.width = cw;
    canvas.height = ch;
    back.width = cw;
    back.height = ch;
    draw(v,context,backcontext,cw,ch);
},false);

function draw(v,c,bc,w,h) {
    if(v.paused || v.ended) return false;
    // First, draw it into the backing canvas
    bc.drawImage(v,0,0,w,h);
    // Grab the pixel data from the backing canvas
    var idata = bc.getImageData(0,0,w,h);
    var data = idata.data;
    // Loop through the pixels, turning them grayscale
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i+=4) {
        var r = data[i];
        var g = data[i+1];
        var b = data[i+2];
        if(r >= lR && r <= hR && g >= lG && g <= hG && b >= lB && b <= hB){
            data[i + 3] = 0;
        }
    }
    idata.data = data;
    // Draw the pixels onto the visible canvas
    c.putImageData(idata,0,0);
    // Start over!
    setTimeout(function(){ draw(v,c,bc,w,h); }, 0);
}
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    background-color: purple;
}

#doh{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 120px;
}
```

**Exception**

SecurityError: DOM Exception 18: An attempted was made to break through the security policy of the user agent.

And as you would expect it is happening on

```
var idata = bc.getImageData(0,0,w,h); Line 41
```